# prevent refetching of data by refresh

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating an online quiz . i am fetching random questions from database and displaying it to user . By refreshing the page will make another request and the user will get a different set of questions . how to prevent that

Comment: store this set in session. On request, check if specific session key is not empty and disply same set of questions to this user.

Comment: k got it just suggest me about about the request about the refresh .. i have not done something like that till now like some snippet how i should proceed

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Nemoden's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413951/prevent-refetching-of-data-by-refresh#comment-18329163):

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();

// if questions were not fetched for this session yet...
if( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'questions' ] ) )
{
    // fetch questions and put in $_SESSION[ 'questions' ]
    $_SESSION[ 'questions' ] = fetchRandomQuestionsFromDatabase();
}

// loop through $_SESSION[ 'questions' ] and do something with each question
foreach( $_SESSION[ 'questions' ] as $question )
{
    // print question, or something
}
```